# How to compare the values of each query using selenium clj-webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, clojure

I want to compare the values of each query using `clj-webdriver`. Each All the query have same class.

For the first query to test if the value is same I used

```
(is (= "2" (text ".class")))
```

But what should I do, to compare all the query values which have same class.

If suppose the questions are

```
What is your favourite number?    2
what is your shoe size?           3
```

Like 10 questions having same class. Please help me how to compare all the queries having same class.

The html code is:

```
<tr data-toggle="coll" href="#623">
    <td class="desc">...</td>
    <td class="foo">
    <span class="fav number">
    <sup class="number number">
    2
    </sup>
    "
    /
    "
    <sub>
    2
    </sub>
    </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
 <tr data-toggle="coll" href="#625">
    <td class="desc">...</td>
    <td class="foo">
    <span class="shoe size">
    <sup class="size number">
    3
    </sup>
    "
    /
    "
    <sub>
    3
    </sub>
    </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Did you check suitable CSS selectors? (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl Not really understanding. Can you give an example of what to use

Comment: Please, fix your question first - it's hard to grasp what you need. In one sentence your write "But what should I do, to compare all the query values which have *different class*" and in another "how to compare all the queries having *same class*". Please, provide a snippet of HTML that you are working with.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl Sorry it's the same class

Comment: could you please update your question then? And include a snippet of HTML from the page you want to test?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl I did.. please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have control over the HTML that is being tested. If you do I strongly recommend to modify it so you have a stable IDs generated for the tested elements so you can identify them easily in your tests:

```
<div id="shoe-size-answer">40</div>
```

Then your tests will be as easy as:

```
(is (text "#shoe-size-answer") "40"))`
```

With IDs you don't need to know the structure of your HTML document and your tests won't break when you rearrange parts of your page (and your IDs won't change).

You can also use some dummy CSS classes to mark some sections of your HTML and navigate nested parts of your page using them:

```
<div class="a1">
  <div class="b1">
    a1b1
  </div>
  <div class="b2">
    a1b2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a2">
  <div class="b1">
    a2b1
  </div>
  <div class="b2">
    a2b2
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can specify queries using CSS paths:

```
(is (text {:css ".a1 .b1"}) "a1b1")
(is (text {:css ".a2 .b1"}) "a2b1")
```

And finally for me the easiest way to get my queries right is to experiment in the REPL. Just start your REPL with your project dependencies on classpath and try:

```
(require '[clj-webdriver.taxi :as taxi])

(taxi/set-driver! {:browser :chrome})

(taxi/to "http://localhost:8000/index.html")

(taxi/find-element {:css ".a1 .b1"})
;; => #clj_webdriver.element.Element{:webelement #<Tag: <div>, Text: a1b1, Class: b1, Object: [[...] -> css selector: .a1 .b1]>}

(taxi/text {:css ".a1 .b1"})
;; => "a1b1"
```

You could even save your tested page as a static HTML file and from the directory where it is saved run the following to get the basic HTTP server working (you need Python installed on your machine):

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

(where `8080` is the server port) and access it at http://localhost:8080. This will allow you to play with the page without the need to reply the whole scenario to get to the tested page.

You could read more about CSS and XPath queries in [many](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) [online](https://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples) [tutorials](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/css-selector-selenium-locator-selenium-tutorial-6/).